# How to run `nuxt generate` in the foreground

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my package.json, I have:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "generate": "nuxt generate & npm run css",
...
```

And run the command via `npm run generate`, with only one issue -- it seems to run in the background, so if I run it in a bash script with additional commands following the generation, they actually run during the generation.  Is there an option to make `nuxt generate` run in the foreground?

Comment: What version of Nuxt are you using?

Answer (score 1):

That‘s because you only have one & in script which means the command before will be sent to the background. Try using && between the commands.

Comment: That makes sense and resolves the issue.  I was thinking that since `npm run generate` wasn't being run with a single `&`, it wouldn't run in the background.